# I need a name for a particular data structure

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I keep running into a certain kind of data structure, and wonder if there is a name for it. It maps very closely to JSON, but not exactly. The rules are:

1. It is composed entirely of maps, arrays, and primitives.
2. It is hierarchical. Maps contain name/value pairs, where a value can
   be another map, an array, or a primitive. Arrays contain values with the same rules.
3. The top level is always a map.
4. The primitives are strings, integers, floats, booleans, and possibly
   dates.
5. Sometimes the map is just an unordered hash, and sometimes the order
   of the name/value pairs matter.

This is a really, really useful structure. You can use it to represent documents, database records, various messages, http requests, lots of stuff. I've run into it in Freemarker (as the 'data model'), Mongo, and anything that uses JSON.

It's not really JSON, because that's a file format, not a specification for a particular data structure. It's not an "object", because object trees can point to other things, like streams and functions. It's not a DOM.

What is it?

Around the office, we've started to call it a "garg", for "generalized argument".

Comment: What were the names used for the classes in the sources you've seen?

Comment: In Java: Map, List, and each primitive gets its own name. In Javascript: it's just an object or variable.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not really JSON, because that's a file format, not a specification for a particular data structure.

It might not **be** JSON (since the specs include syntax rules), but your structure definition defines the same data structure as JSON does.

I don't think it's useful to name this structure. When you are talking about data, just call it **data**. When you need to interchange data you need a **data-interchange format**. Now JSON proves to be one damn good one.

Answer (score 0):

JSON isn't just a file format. JSON is also a data structure.

From JSON.org

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> 1. A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>    realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>    list, or associative array.
> 2. An ordered list of values. In most
>    languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.
>
> These are universal data structures.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), with optional ordering.

That's what JSON represents, except that (I believe) JSON doesn't impose an ordering requirement.  Naturally, many other representations also describe associative arrays, which is why JSON is a popular text serialization.

---

Update 1: JSON isn't properly an associative array.  It is a description of object properties.  Because it is very often construed as an associative array, many people make the same mistake I did.  In fact, "object notation" is the proper name for it - surprise, surprise.  :)  In addition, JSON isn't a file format - it's a text serialization or markup language, which is different from a file format.

Comment: That describes the map part of the structure, but not the rest of the rules.

Comment: I believe that is incorrect, but perhaps you can clarify.  I see no restrictions on an associative array satisfying attributes 2-5.  As JSON is an instantiation of an associative array, then general associative arrays satisfy *at least* as much functionality as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It is a generic data storage structure that carries around hierarchical data. I don't have a generic name for it, but if I were to implement such a beast in, say, C++, I'd probably call the abstract base class a `Variant`, and name the concrete types by their names: `Integer`, `Array`, `Map`, etc. I'd chuck them in a namespace that would relate to where I'd use them - or maybe I'd prefix the types themselves. I've seen such structures used as well, but I don't know if there is a name that I'd recognize. A `DataStore`, `Environment`, `StorageBin`, or anything that is generic and implies storage of data would do.

I don't see myself calling such a class hierarchy `JSON`, though. I would provide a `JsonSerializer` or some such to map this data to JSON, if I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is a **tree** with different kinds of values stored at its leafs.
In Boost, a similar structure is called *Property Tree*.